# JAVA JSONArray sort in reverse order

Tags: java, android

I have JSON array like this:

```
[{"BMW": [], "OPEL": [], "Mercedes": []}]
```

and I want to get

```
[{"Mercedes": [], "OPEL": [], "BMW": []}]
```

How can I make like this?

Comment: Why, what's the point?

Answer (score 8):

Since JSONObjects are not keeping their order in which you build them (has to do with how it's handled in memory) you should refactor the data.

```
[{"BMW": [], "OPEL": [], "Mercedes": []}]
```

to

```
[{"BMW":[]}, {"OPEL":[]}, {"Mercedes":[]}]
```

That still won't help you right away though since JSONArray in java doesn't appear to have reverse() method :(

So like I commented: build a new JSONArray in reverse order:

```
JSONArray newJsonArray = new JSONArray()
for (int i = jsonArray.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    newJsonArray.put(jsonArray.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A small yet best solution to this is to store the JSON array in reverse order:

```
    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("records");
    for (int i = array.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
         // Perform your regular JSON Parsing here
}
```

You dont need to edit / change your JSON

Answer (score 1):

You have a JSON object, not an array. An object is comprised of key-value pairs, but these pairs are not ordered by key in any way. In fact, the order should not matter - the representation is the same.

From the ECMAScript spec, as copied here: http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-4.html

> 4.3.3 Object An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered collection of properties each of which contains a primitive
>   value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an
>   object is called a method.

Comment: Agreed in principle, but Javascript defines arrays in terms of objects with properties anyway, so....

Comment: I need to sort in reverse order. I'm making my first application in android and I'm beginner in java. I'd couldn't find solution, so I asked here

Comment: @PiraTa , what is it that are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've some data in list view. I want to user can sort it in DESC or ASC

Comment: Downvoted because he has a JSONArray with JSONObjects. Also, he's talking about java, not js? He wants to reverse the JSONArray, not the objects that are found in it. For as far as I have been able to find (up until now, been googling for ~10 minutes) the best bet is to create an ArrayList from the JSONArray and then call Collections.reverse(list). Or just build a new JSONArray with for(int i=jsonarray.length()-1; i>=0; i--) { /*...*/ }?

Comment: OOOPS nvm, He does want to reverse the jsonobject INSIDE the array. Still, it's a java question (also tagged as java), not javascript :) Anyway, removed downvote